# Schedule to the batch. By launching a single class (CRON creation)

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I want to automation of the different steps by adding a schedule to the batch. By launching a single class (CRON creation).
Setup the launch of the multiple phase throughout the time.

Example:

- Phase 1 : NOW + 1hour
- Phase 2: NOW + 6 days
- Phase 3: NOW + 10 days
- Phase 4: NOW + 12 day

How to set the CRON_EXPR for the above phases?

I have created this class. Could anyone plase help me to complete this class?

```
global class ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail implements Schedulable {

      /*
        Call this from Anonymous Apex to schedule at the default regularity
      */
  global static String schedulePhase1() {
    Datetime sysTime = System.now().addHours(1); 
    String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
    ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail job = new ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail();
    return System.schedule('Email Anonymization Phase1', chronExpression, job);
  }
  global static String schedulePhase2() {
    Datetime sysTime = System.now().addDays(6); 
    String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
    ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail job = new ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail();
    return System.schedule('Email Anonymization Phase2', chronExpression, job);
  }
  global static String schedulePhase3() {
    Datetime sysTime = System.now().addDays(10); 
    String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
    ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail job = new ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail();
    return System.schedule('Email Anonymization Phase3', chronExpression, job);
  }
  global static String schedulePhase4() {
    Datetime sysTime = System.now().addDays(12); 
    String chronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
    ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail job = new ScheduleBatch_AnonymizeEmail();
    return System.schedule('Email Anonymization Phase4', chronExpression, job);
  }

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    // This is good practice if you are likely to be processing a
    // lot of records at a time
    Batch_Class b = new Batch_Class ();
    Database.executeBatch(b);
  }
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: @kurunve I have updated my solution in the question. Is this correct?

Comment: Seems to be correct